# VScode integrated terminal suddenly throws an error during initialization

Tags: bash, shell, visual-studio-code, zsh

I'm using the most recent VScode on Ubuntu 22.10 and experiencing the following issues while opening ZSH and BASH shells in the integrated terminal. The standard Ubuntu terminal works without errors.

After starting a ZSH integrated terminal:

```
compdump:138: command not found: mv
/home/user/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:56: command not found: mkdir
/home/user/.oh-my-zsh/tools/check_for_upgrade.sh:29: command not found: git
/home/user/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:115: command not found: rm
getent:6: command not found: grep
_p9k_init_cacheable:59: command not found: uname
_p9k_init_cacheable:61: command not found: uname
```

BASH

```
Command 'uname' is available in the following places
 * /bin/uname
 * /usr/bin/uname
The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
uname: command not found
```

Just several hours before, it worked just fine. Then I tried to set up Remote SSH to another Linux machine (Fedora 36, with the same sort of errors I was also unable to resolve by googling).

Using the @modified keyword in Settings, I ensured that no unexpected changes had been made. The PATH is the same as in the fully operational standard terminal.

Wondering what could be the issue.

**UPDATES.**

PATH variable:

`/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin:/home/user/.conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH`

**The problem.**

Unlike the complete PATH expansion in the standard terminal, PATH was expanded partially (omitting /usr/bin, etc.) in the integrated terminal.

Comment: What machine are you getting these errors from? You said that you SSHd into another machine, Im wondering if these errors are coming from that machine or the machine that you SSHd from.

Comment: This is Ubuntu 22.10 machine, while the one I tried to SSH to has Fedora 36.

Comment: Makes sense, are these logs coming from the Ubuntu machine or the Fedora machine?

Comment: Everything in the post comes from the Ubuntu machine

Comment: Can you add the output of ```echo $PATH```

Comment: Added. It doesn't seem informative...

Comment: Your PATH variable should NOT contain `:$PATH`. Run this command to see if any initialization files have been updated recently : `/usr/bin/ls -dltr ~/.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this error,

`The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.`

I suggest you run,

`export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"`

To add `/bin:/usr/bin` to your `PATH`

Having `:$PATH` in your `PATH` means that the sheell will add the variable `$PATH` to the end of your `PATH`

Comment: Thank you, PATH was the right direction to look deeper. Faced some weird VScode behavior on expanding PATH from settings.json. Still, it is strange that the error list is that small without /usr/bin and friends.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue the following configuration from the User settings:

```
terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "/media/user:/media/user/common:$PYTHONPATH",
    "PATH": "/media/user:/media/user/common:$PATH"
}
```

While the PYTHONPATH variable is expanded properly in the integrated terminal, the PATH is expanded **partially** to something shown in the UPDATES section of the question. To build on top of the answer by @Orion447, looking for any potential place where PATH could get corrupted is the approach that likely solves the problem.